# Angular 2 - Get form control validators

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I just want to know how to get the list of validators of a form control?

I have a custom validator wherein it will only take effect after a certain condition. My plan is to fetch the list of validators of the form control and push the custom validator that I created.

Thank you!

Comment: Me too I just want to know how to get the list of validators of a form control?...

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the validator list, since it's an internal list of functions.
You can inspect the control.errors for the current list of active validators.